# gnome workspace navagation shortcuts for both left and right ctrl/alt?

Tags: shortcut-keys, workspaces

A few months ago I noticed that I could no longer use <kbd>R-CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R-ALT</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> to switch between workspaces. The only thing that seems to work is <kbd>L-CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L-ALT</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> . The gsetting key only says <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd>

Is there a way to make this work for both left and right?